# É possível chamar/enxergar plugin cordova da aplicação android de um site externo que é aberto dentro do app?

Tags: android, angularjs, apache-cordova, google-play

Tenho um app simples utilizando o cordova, dentro, chamo uma aplicação web externa desenvolvida em AngularJS.
Pretendo iniciar monetização no app, e para isso quero realizar vendas através da Google Play Store, dentro dele.
Para tal, eu preciso de dentro dessa aplicação web externa, chamar o javascript/plugin inAppPurchase que já foi adicionado ao projeto.

Acontece, que óbviamente, diretamente isso não é possível.
Atualmente, minha chamada para a aplicação externa está assim:

```js
<script>
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
    if (navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
      networkError()
    } else {
      loadApp()
    }
  }

  function loadApp() {
    navigator.app.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.102:8000/")
  }
</script>
```

O plugin que quero chamar: InAppPurchase - https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

Chamando do index.html do projeto cordova ele funciona direitinho, agora da aplicação externa, apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: inAppPurchase is not defined

A chamada no index do projeto externo que é chamado dentro do app está dessa forma:

```js
<script>
  inAppPurchase.getProducts(['vaga_de_veiculo'])
    .then(function (products) {
      console.log(products);
    })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
</script>
```

Estou tentando agora com o inAppBrowser, mas também não obtive sucesso.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, espero que ajude outros.
SOLUÇÃO FUNCIONA APENAS PARA ANDROID.

A chamada no index.html na pasta www do projeto cordova ficou da seguinte forma:

```js
<script>
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
    if (navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
      networkError()
    } else {
      loadApp()
    }
  }

  function loadApp() {
    window.open("http://192.168.0.102:8000/", "_system");
  }
</script>
```

O config.xml precisou ter as seguintes linhas informadas:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.102:8000/*" />
```

Precisei alterar a classe **SystemWebViewClient.java** do cordova. Ela fica localizada em **\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemWebViewClient.java** adicionando as seguintes instruções:

Declarar variável que será injetada na chamada de javascript na sua aplicação externa:

```
private static final String INJECTION_TOKEN = "**injection**";
```

Localize o método: **shouldInterceptRequest** e logo após o **try{** adicione o seguinte código:

```
if(url != null && url.contains(INJECTION_TOKEN)) {
String assetPath = url.substring(url.indexOf(INJECTION_TOKEN) + INJECTION_TOKEN.length(), url.length());
try {
    String mimeType = "text/plain";

    String ext = assetPath.substring(assetPath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, assetPath.length());
    WebExtension extension = WebExtension.valueOf(ext.toUpperCase());

    switch(extension) {
        case PNG:
            mimeType = "image/png";
            break;
        case MP3:
            mimeType = "audio/mpeg";
            break;
        case MP4:
            mimeType = "video/mp4";
            break;
        case TTF:
            mimeType = "application/x-font-ttf";
            break;
        case SVG:
            mimeType = "image/svg+xml";
            break;
        case JS:
            mimeType = "application/javascript";
            break;
        case ICO:
            mimeType = "image/x-icon";
            break;
        case HTML:
            mimeType = "text/html";
            break;
        case CSS:
            mimeType = "text/css";
            break;
        case EOT:
            mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-fontobject";
            break;
        case WOFF:
            mimeType = "application/x-font-woff";
            break;
        case JSON:
            mimeType = "application/json";
            break;
    }

    WebResourceResponse response = new WebResourceResponse(
        mimeType,
        "UTF-8",
        parentEngine.webView.getContext().getAssets().open(assetPath)
    );
    return response;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // Failed to load asset file
}}
```

Configuração terminada no cordova, **agora no seu projeto externo web**, você adiciona a seguinte chamada, **no index.html** (se for o caso):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="**injection**www/cordova.js"></script>
```

Dessa forma, seu projeto web consegue acessar as APIs Cordova. Testei o plugin inAppPurchase e funcionou direitinho.